# How to calculate a series with binomial terms invovled

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus

I'm studying probability and having trouble in understanding the following calculation

[image]

How to get from left to the right on the first line, with the condition that m could only be even numbers? Any hint would be appreciated, thanks~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We write the same thing, with different symbols. We have 
$$(x+y)^k =\binom{n}{0}x^0y^k+\binom{k}{1}xy^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}x^2y^{k-2}+\binom{k}{3}x^3y^{n-3}+\cdots.$$
Also,
$$(x-y)^k =\binom{n}{0}x^0y^k-\binom{k}{1}xy^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}x^2y^{k-2}-\binom{k}{3}x^3y^{k-3}+\cdots.$$
Add, and observe the cancellation. We get
$$(x+y)^k+(x-y)^k=2\binom{k}{0}x^0y^k+2\binom{k}{2}x^2y^{k-2}+2\binom{k}{4}x^4y^{n-4}+\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0):

Go from right to left, instead. Note that

\begin{align*}
\left[\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{1}{n}\right]^k &= \sum_m {k \choose m} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k - m} \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m} \\
&= \sum_m {k \choose m} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k - m} (-1)^m \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^m
\end{align*}

Likewise, we can compare this to the other term being added:

$$\left[\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{n}\right]^k = \sum_m {k \choose m} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k - m} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m}$$

Since $(-1)^m = -1$ if $m$ is odd, the terms corresponding to that $m$ will cancel. When $m$ is even, we'll get two copies of the same term - hence we have to divide by $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: thanks for your help!! Though I actually need to know how to go from left to the right, it's still very helpful!!